# How multiple docker containers can be used on Heroku?

Tags: docker, heroku

I want to use two containers Golang web server and Mysql Database.
And then I prepared two Dockerfiles and pushed on Heroku.
However web server can not be connected to mysql server.

How is link set from web server to mysql??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't link containers in Heroku unless you use the DockHero plugin there (which costs you money), so that you can use Docker Swarm. In your case it would be better just to use the ClearDB MySQL plugin they provide, and only deploy the first container.