# How to deploy frontend and backend in same heroku applications but different docker images

Tags: docker, heroku, devops

I'm creating a web application that has Angular for front end and Flask for back end. I already 'dockered' my applications but I'm not sure on how to get them in Heroku as the same application

I've been reading that some people has used a reverse proxy server (this means that both applications are in different heroku app and they connect them using a proxy like traeffik or haproxy). But I don't want to do this, I want them to be in the same application (Example: `grupo-camporota.herokuapp.com`)

I was thinking that I should push both images, one as web dyno (front) and the other one as a worker (backend) but I've read that the worked dyno it's not for this, but for EXTERNAL apis. I would like to upload both image into heroku and make them communicate between them.

I would like to know how to get this done (I'm pretty sure it's possible), since i'm kinda lost

Answer (score 4):

Your backend can't be a worker dyno: [only web dynos can receive traffic from the internet](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#the-web-process-type). And one app will only [get a single port to listen on](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/runtime-principles#web-servers), so you can't run two services on a single app.

You could serve your front-end up from your back-end as static files, but I don't think that will work with Docker. Also, Flask doesn't like to serve static files itself, so that may not be a good fit either.

It also [looks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45616678/354577) [like](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49999920/354577) you can't communicate between Docker containers using a private network on Heroku. You may just have to deploy two apps (or host your front-end on a more appropriate static host).

Comment: Thanks for answering Chris. So do you think my options are: Or changing to another host (like AWS) or creating two applications? – Cesar 10 mins ago   Delete

Comment: Yes, I think those are two good options @Cesar. If you want you can even keep your back-end on Heroku and move just your front-end to AWS. That might have latency issues, but you can always try it out. And since Heroku itself runs on AWS it might not be too bad.